# How to handle 403 HTTP error in restify?

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-403, restify

I've been trying to handle HTTP error in restify. these are the codes i've been trying so far :

```
function send403(req, res, err, cb) {
  console.log('Forbidden');
  res.end();
}
```

And then i use that function in `ForbiddenError` event :

```
server.on('ForbiddenError', send403);
```

I'm expecting that function to be executed everytime server receive a request without `authorization` header

```
server.get('/resource', function (req, res, next) {
  if(typeof req.headers['authorization'] === 'undefined') {
    return next(new restify.ForbiddenError());
  }
  else {
    // HTTP 200
  }
});
```

Everytime i try to access the url i keep getting that default restify JSON message.

FYI i've tried the same method for 404 error and it works

```
server.on('NotFound', send404);
```

Everytime i try to send a request to a non-existing url, the `send404` function will be executed.

Comment: if you want to get value from header or body, I suggest you to use  var urVaribleHere  = req.body.varible || ''; also what part that you don't understand from restify? because everytime user send a url that doesn't exist will not be executed and wil be send 404 webPage Notfound.

Comment: @GujaratSantana Terribly sorry if the question is misleading, i'm not an english speaker. The default behaviour of restify for HTTP error is to send a response in JSON format. Basically what i'm trying to do here is to make it do something else, like say make a log for specific HTTP error. I've tried the `server.on('NotFound', fn)` event and it works, but the `server.on('ForbiddenError', fn)` doesn't work.

Comment: so you are trying to send JSON with server.on('ForbiddenError', fn) to client. I can't help you with code but maybe this link will help you to get better understanding http://thejackalofjavascript.com/architecting-a-restful-node-js-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for. I noticed that in the "server.on" statement restify doesn't want the "Error" part. The following is a complete working example.

```
'use strict';
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.on('Forbidden', send403);

server.get('/resource', function(req, res, next){
    if(typeof req.headers['authorization'] === 'undefined') {
        next(new restify.ForbiddenError());
    }
    else {
        // HTTP 200
    }
});

function send403(req, res, err, cb){
    console.log('Log something here');
    return cb();
}

server.listen(9000);
console.log('listening on port 9000');
```